# How do i reference a resource created from different module in my current module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**How my directory is structured**

```
├── directory
    ├── vpc
    │   └── main.tf
    ├── eks
        └── main.tf
```

**Inside vpc/main.tf**

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "other-tools-vpc"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  # inside 2 azs, create two private subnets and two public subnets each 
  azs             = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b"]
  private_subnets = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24"]

  // remaining code
}
```

**Inside eks/main.tf**

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "18.29.0"

  cluster_name    = "other-tools-eks"
  cluster_version = "1.23"

  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true 
  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true

  vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets

  // remaining code
}
```

I want to assign my vpc created above to my eks cluster. I have tried the following above `vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id` but it produces an error of:

Reference to undeclared module. No module call named "vpc" is declared in the root module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is correct. You can't reference variables or outputs accross different modules. Instead you should have **parrent** `main.tf` folder:

```
├── directory
    |-- parrent_main.tf 
    ├── vpc
    │   └── main.tf
    ├── eks
        └── main.tf
```

and in the `parrent_main.tf` you have to instantiate **both modules**:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "other-tools-vpc"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  # inside 2 azs, create two private subnets and two public subnets each 
  azs             = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b"]
  private_subnets = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24"]

  // remaining code
}

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "18.29.0"

  cluster_name    = "other-tools-eks"
  cluster_version = "1.23"

  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true 
  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true

  vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets

  // remaining code
}
```

Once you do this, `vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id` will work.

**alternatively**

Deploy `vpc` module first, and then deploy `eks` module and pass in  `vpc_id` as an **input variabile** into `eks/main.tf`:

```
variable "vpc_id" {}
variable "private_subnets" {}

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "18.29.0"

  cluster_name    = "other-tools-eks"
  cluster_version = "1.23"

  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true 
  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true

  vpc_id     = var.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = var.private_subnets

  // remaining code
}
```